# Remote SSH: Disk quota exceeded

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, quota

I use vscode to connect to a supercomputer using SSH remote.

I ran a selenium request from a jupyter notebook that took too long, then failed and then the `bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Disk quota exceeded` started to appear when trying to complete with tab the name of a file/folder in the terminal.

These are the outputs of df and quota commands:

```
>> df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                             189G     0  189G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                189G  2.6G  186G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                189G   17M  189G   1% /run
tmpfs                                189G     0  189G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_root    1.0T   44G  981G   5% /
/dev/sda2                           1014M  315M  700M  31% /boot
/dev/sda1                            100M   12M   89M  12% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_tmp     1.0T   26G  999G   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_vartmp  200G  379M  200G   1% /var/tmp
tmpfs                                 38G   12K   38G   1% /run/user/42
home                                  51T   19T   32T  37% /home
proj                                 4.4P  3.6P  801T  83% /proj
sw7                                   21T  4.9T   16T  25% /software
tmpfs                                 38G     0   38G   0% /run/user/10754

>> df -i
Filesystem                             Inodes     IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs                             49329535       638  49328897    1% /dev
tmpfs                                49339830      1050  49338780    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                49339830      5418  49334412    1% /run
tmpfs                                49339830        16  49339814    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_root   107374144    262482 107111662    1% /
/dev/sda2                              524288        27    524261    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                                   0         0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_tmp    107374144     33180 107340964    1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_vartmp 104857600       518 104857082    1% /var/tmp
tmpfs                                49339830         9  49339821    1% /run/user/42
home                                157286400  84893563  72392837   54% /home
proj                                500000000 343005480 156994520   69% /proj
sw7                                 104857600  33867547  70990053   33% /software
tmpfs                                49339830        10  49339820    1% /run/user/10754

>> quota -u
Disk quotas for user ***** (uid 10754): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/vg_loginnode1-lv_tmp
                10485760* 10485760 10485760           22639       0       0
```

Obviously, I am surpassing the quota. As I told you at the beginning, this is a supercomputer, so I have limited to no access to the base folders (tmp, etc.). So, any ideas on how to solve this without cleaning tmp are more than welcome.

Comment: Did you run a Selenium script in a Jupyter notebook on the login node of a supercomputer?

Comment: Obvious answer: remove files in the over-quota filesystem. The only way I know to write in a filesystem that is already full is making more space.

Comment: Run `du ~ | sort -nr | head` to see what takes up space in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue. I cannot find any files that I own in /tmp, so I don't know why the system says my tmp quota is exceeded.

I found a work-around: change the location of my bash temp files.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp
$ export TMPDIR=~/tmp
$ echo "export TMPDIR=~/tmp" >> ~/.bashrc
```